# Why is this making a GET request to the same page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I  have a form

```
    <form id="registration-form">
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname" id="name" placeholder="Enter Partner Name Here">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eaddr" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address Here">
        </fieldset> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Take Survey</button> 
        <p><span class="errmsg" id="reg-error"></span></p>        
    </form>
```

and my intention is that submitting it invokes the AJAX call

```
    $('#registration-form').submit(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : '/Account/AddPartner',
            method : 'POST',
            data : {
                pname: $('input[name="pname"]').val(),
                eaddr: $('input[name="eaddr"').val()
            },
        // ...
    });
```

which if successful redirects them to a new page and if not successful returns an error message that is displayed. The controller that handles this is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPartner ( string pname, string eaddr )
    {
        Guid? newpid = this._Db.AddPartner(pname, eaddr);
        if ( newpid != null )
        {
            return RedirectToAction("FillOut", "Answers", new { pid = newpid }); // should redirect to /Answers/FillOut?pid=newpid
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { msg = "Failed get id of partner"} );
        }
   }
```

What's happening, for some strange reason, is that when the form is submitted a GET question is being made to the same page the form is on, e.g.

> /Account/Register?pname=klaskdljaskldjas&eaddr=akdalkkldjkl%40hotmail.com

What is going on here?

Comment: Are there any JS errors in the console when you submit the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedirectToAction will not work from ajax request, you have to redirect from client side after success ajax call.

Also, you lost one pair "})" in your javascript

Comment: Just to add onto this, I'd suggest returning a Json object with either success or fail then with the redirect action aswell which will then be evaluated by your Ajax on success/complete function.